# How to perform a mean comparison in R, with a treatment factor, that have 3 levels?

Tags: r

Can you please help me to understand how to perform a comparison of the means in R?
the Treatment factor has 3 Levels and i want to compare the mean of the yield at each  level of the treatment factor for significance

how to write the Argument to make R understand that he should compare the mean.yield when Treatment=75 (is a factor, not numeric) to mean.yield when Treatment=100 and also when Treatment=125?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by comparison? Difference, % change, statistical difference, etc.

Comment: This isn't clear. An ANOVA compares the means of multiple levels of a factor. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an all-pairwise comparison using the `multcomp` package.

```
library(multcomp)

mydata <- data.frame(treatment=c("75", "100", "125","75", "100", "125","75", "100", "125"),
                     mean.yield=c(10,20,30,20,25,27,3,15,12))

immer.aov <- aov(mean.yield ~ treatment, data = mydata)
immer.mc  <- glht(immer.aov, linfct = mcp(treatment = "Tukey"))

summary(immer.mc)
```

> ```
>    Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
>
> Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
>
>
> Fit: aov(formula = mean.yield ~ treatment, data = mydata)
>
> Linear Hypotheses:
>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
> 125 - 100 == 0    3.000      6.515   0.460    0.892
> 75 - 100 == 0    -9.000      6.515  -1.381    0.407
> 75 - 125 == 0   -12.000      6.515  -1.842    0.235
> (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
> ```

For more details and options please check out the package documentation and [this](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/Biblio/R_eng/Bretz%20Multiple%20Comparisons.pdf) resource.

Comment: Thank you very much. It could help. But i still have one question.... the results of the linear hypothesis... on my console, I only got the estimate value for the pairwise comparisons, but not the Std.E, the t-value and de p-value.
What could be the reason?

Comment: I should say, my data Frame is really small. Only 2values on each Level of Treatment. Can it be the reason, why the t- and p-value cannot be estimated?

Comment: @simie yep that would be the reason